# com.google.cloud.functions.HttpRequest instance does not support form-data with more than 1 file on the same field

Tags: java, google-cloud-functions, form-data

I am creating a `gcloud` *http* Cloud Function which must receive a "**form-data**" form with a "**medias**" field which can contain up to 3 files, here is the basic code:

gcloud Java function :

```
package functions;

import com.google.cloud.functions.HttpFunction;
import com.google.cloud.functions.HttpRequest;
import com.google.cloud.functions.HttpResponse;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;

public class HelloWorld implements HttpFunction {
  @Override
  public void service(HttpRequest request, HttpResponse response)
      throws IOException {
    var parts = request.getParts();

    parts.forEach(
            (e1, e2) -> {
                System.out.println(e1);
                System.out.println(e2.getFileName().get());
            });


  }
}
```

My simple request :

```
curl --location --request POST 'http://localhost:8080/' \
--form 'medias=@"/file1.jpeg"' \
--form 'medias=@"/file2.jpeg"'
```

Oddly, `"request.getParts();"` returns a `"Map<String, HttpPart>"` and therefore I don't see how to retrieve multiple files of the same submitted parameter. In debugging, I get a nice:

> "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Duplicate key medias (attempted merging values com.google.cloud.functions.invoker.http.HttpRequestImpl$HttpPartImpl@49e848cf

and

> com.google.cloud.functions.invoker.http .HttpRequestImpl$HttpPartImpl@6d5d7015)"

The same query works without problem with "Springboot" by specifying this as a parameter:

```
@RequestParam(value = "medias", required = false) MultipartFile[] medias
```

So do you think it's a bug with this dependency?

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.cloud.functions</groupId>
    <artifactId>functions-framework-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.4</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I can see that "getQueryParameters()" return correctly "Map<String, List<String>>" and not "Map<String, String>" because a parameter name can have many value but why "getParts()" return "Map<String, HttpPart>" and not "Map<String, List<HttpPart>>" ?

Comment: I don't see any issue with the functions-framework-api dependency. Can you also provide the complete stacktrace so we can isolate which code triggers the error? @elgsylvain85

Comment: @CatherineO are you able to submit a "form-data" form with several files on the same parameter like this : curl --location --request POST 'http://localhost:8080/' \
--form 'medias=@"/file1.jpeg"' \
--form 'medias=@"/file2.jpeg"'

Comment: I was able to reproduce your issue and provided a workaround. I've also posted my answer. @elgsylvain85

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in this GCP [docs](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/http#multipart_data), you can process the data with a multipart/form-data content type by using the sample code below.

```java
for (HttpRequest.HttpPart httpPart : request.getParts().values()) {
      String filename = httpPart.getFileName().orElse(null);
      if (filename == null) {
        continue;
      }
      
      //do something here
}
```

I've done some tests using your scenario and tried manipulating the `getParts()` method using `java.util.stream.Collectors` to come up with a solution like `Map<String, List<HttpPart>>` but failed. It seems that it's not possible to use the same parameter key for each form-data.

I also checked the source code of the `HttpRequest.getParts()` method and found out that it has its own way of collecting the stream from the form-data  that is failing when there's only a single key for each data as seen below:

```java
public Map<String, HttpRequest.HttpPart> getParts() {
    String contentType = this.request.getContentType();
    if (contentType == null || this.request.getContentType().startsWith("multipart/form-data"))
        throw new IllegalStateException("Content-Type must be multipart/form-data: " + contentType);
     try {
         return (Map<String, HttpRequest.HttpPart>)this.request.getParts().stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(Part::getName, x -> new HttpPartImpl(x)));
     } catch (IOException e) {
         throw new UncheckedIOException(e);
     } catch (ServletException e) {
         throw new RuntimeException(e.getMessage(), e);
     }
}
```

Finally, my suggestion is to use "unique" parameter key for each form-data.

```js
curl --location --request POST 'http://localhost:8080/' --form 'medias[item]=@file1.jpeg' --form 'medias[item1]=@file2.jpeg'
```

Comment: Exactly @Catherine, there is not issue with query parameters because "request.getQueryParameters()" return "Map<String, List<String>>" but "request.getParts()" return "Map<String, HttpPart>". The problem is that it considerably limits the dynamics.